# quotation, in bash, does not work for very long string

Tags: string, bash

I have a very long string and i put it in '' in bash. But the bash recognize only a portion of the string ( please see the attached picture) and it is like the rest of string is not in quotations. How many character string should be in bash? How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please try to provide a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- part of being code *other people can use* to reproduce a problem is that it should be in a format amenable to being copied and pasted, rather than provided as an image; and that there should be a clear description of "I'm running X, expect output Y, and get output Z instead". Since the image linked only shows a string -- but not any code, expected output or actual output -- it's unclear how to interpret it.

Comment: (And to be clear -- bash has no innate maximum-string-length limit. There's an OS-dependent limit on the maximum combined length of command-line arguments when an external command is being invoked, but we'd need to actually see the error you're getting to determine whether that's involved).

Comment: tried 1GB long string - (1_000_000_000 chars) and the `${#str}` prints: 1000000000. so...

Comment: (By the way -- if you need some time to edit a question, you can effectively pause feedback by deleting it, editing it while it's deleted, and then undeleting when it's ready).

Comment: Actually -- this is a screenshot from your editor (emacs or vim or such), right? I'd bet literal money that it's just a limitation of your editor's syntax highlighting, and nothing to do with actual bash behavior at all. You might consider editing the question to revolve around the text editor itself.

Answer (score -3):

You can put the strings in a file and use pipe instead.

e.g. `cat str | xargs mycmd`

Comment: This doesn't actually increase the maximum length of a single argument, and it changes the original behavior -- of explicitly failing when a command's argument list won't fit in the process environment -- to a new behavior of running `mycmd` several times, each with a shorter argument list. Moreover, it re-parses your string, rather than passing content through literally: Quotes, spaces, and other content are treated as syntactic rather than literal unless extensions such as `xargs -0` or `xargs -d $'\n'` are in use.

Comment: But, to the point: Any single argument you could pass with xargs, you could also successfully pass with `mycmd "$str"`.